# Using the Mean Value Theorem for proof

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable at $(0,1)$, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, I am supposed to prove that:

$a)$ $\exists c$ such that $f(c) = 1 - c$
$b)$ $\exists a,b$ such that $f'(a) f'(b) = 1$

Using MVT, I have shown that there exists c such that 
\begin{align} f'(c) & = \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0}  \\
& = 1 \end{align}
 but how do I reach the conclusion in part $a)$?

Also, how would I start approaching $b)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $h(x) = f(x)+x-1$.

Now, $h(0)=-1$ and $h(1) = 1$. Therfore, there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $h(c) = 0 \Rightarrow f(c) + c - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)+x-1$ and use the Intermediate Value Theorem.